# How do I write a function that converts all consonant strings at the start of each word in a sentence into an "r" until it runs into a vowel?

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions

SCOOBY DOO CHALLENGE

> You are required to write a function that replaces all consonants at
>   the start of a word until it runs into a vowel with an "r". For
>   example, the word "**scooby**" would become "**rooby**" and “**xylophone**” would
>   become “**rophone**”

This is the function that I'm using but it only operates on a single word in my sentences. How can I make it operate on every word.

```
function scooby_doo () {
    if (text.value.length == 0) {
        result.value = "no input given!";
    } else if (text.value.length > 0) {
        var set = text.value.split(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            result.value = set[i].replace (/^[^aeiou]+/i, "r");
        }
     } else {
        result.value = "";
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: result.value += " " + your stuff, after result.value =""

Comment: your question is not clear what is `result` what is `text` is there any HTML involved you should add a complete set of requirements before you ask for an urgent solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you could achieve that with no explicit loops:

```
str = 'scooby doo loves his xylophone show';
str.replace(/(^| |\n)[^aeiou]+/ig, '$1r');
// outputs "rooby roo roves ris rophone row"
```

Is this what you are looking for as the output?

Comment: Amazing regex there.

Comment: Instead of `^| |\n`, why not just `\b`? This would also avoid needing to use `$1`.

Comment: Yes, that could be used as well, but if you only do that, the words would all be glued together, like "roobyroorovesrisrophonerow"
Probably could be used with a little tweak.

Comment: @FelipeNMoura I've accepted your answer. That's one hell of a regular expression. Can you walk me through how you came about it. How does this work. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, the idea is that the group `(^| |\n)` (remember, everything in between `()` is grouped) will look for anything that was one of:

- the beginning of the string
- an empty space
- a new line symbol (`\n`)

If anything matched that, it would "then" look for anything that was NOT a vowel `[^aeiou]` right after the matching group. The plus sign means there might be more characters.

After then, I replace those matches by the matching group (either a new line or a space) and the letter `r`.

The `/ig` means it is not case sensitive and can match multiple times in the same string.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your code you override the previous value when you use :

```
result.value = set[i].replace ( /^[^aeiou]+/i, "r" );
```

I dind't know the type of `result` but you can try this solution:

```
function scooby_doo (text) {

var result = [];
if ( text.length == 0 )
{
    return 'no input given';
} else if ( text.length > 0 ) {
    var set = text.split ( " " );
    for ( i = 0; i < set.length; i++ ) {
        result.push(set[i].replace ( /^[^aeiou]+/i, "r" ));
    }
 } else {
    return '';
}

 return result.join(' ');
}
```

`console.log('scooby xylophone')`:

```
"rooby rophone"
```